# Unity | Getting Parse Relational Data from within a Subclass

Tags: c#, ios, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I'm running into a **GetRelation problem** when I try to query it from within a Subclass parse object. It's working fine in the Unity Editor, but I'm getting an error "**InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Job' to type 'ParseUser'**" at the foreach when I try to run the app on an iOS device.

The subclass is setup correctly with RegisterSubclass() and I'm able to access all data of that Job subclass when fetched. (fetching pointer data is working fine as well)

Any idea why it's running into this error on iOS? I'm using Unity 5.2.1f1 and Parse 1.6.2

**Update:** Apparently it works with a non il2cpp version.

```
var jobsRelation = ParseUser.CurrentUser.GetRelation<ParseObject>("jobs");
var q = jobsRelation.Query;     
var t = q.FindAsync();

while (!t.IsCompleted) {
    yield return 0;
}

if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.Log (query.Exception);
} else {
    Debug.Log ("Got list of jobs" );

    IEnumerable<ParseObject> relatedObjects = t.Result;

    foreach (var entry in relatedObjects) { //loop through jobs
        if(entry==null) Debug.Log ("entry is null. something is wrong");
        Debug.Log(entry.ClassName + " id: " + entry.ObjectId);

        var reference= ParseObject.CreateWithoutData<Job>(entry.ObjectId);
        var fetchtask = reference.FetchAsync(); //fetch job data
        while (!fetchtask.IsCompleted) {yield return null;}  //wait on parse

        //query "people" relation of a Job
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> peopleQuery= reference.GetRelation<ParseUser>("people").Query;
        Task<IEnumerable<ParseUser>> peopleTask= peopleQuery.FindAsync();

        while(!peopleTask.IsCompleted){ yield return 0;}

        IEnumerable<ParseUser> result = peopleTask.Result;

        foreach( ParseUser _user in result ){ //<--- ERROR HERE
            //do stuff with _user
        }   
    }
}
```